# take action on vs take action

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "take action on" and "take action"?
I searched on the internet but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Take action on* is not a distinct idiom; rather, the word *action* licenses a preposition phrase headed by *on* as a complement designating the problem or domain to which the action is directed.

> **A:** At last! Management has taken action!
>   **B:** Action on what?
>   **A:** Action on our petition to eliminate Durham cutlets from the cafeteria menu!